# Column sizes sometimes do not fit when I move data from table 'TABLE_1' to table 'TABLE_2'. oracle is sending an error as follows

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I want to move data from one table to a table.
I wrote one plsql code for this process.
Column sizes sometimes do not fit when I move data from table 'TABLE_1' to table 'TABLE_2'.
oracle is sending an error as follows.

I have identified one exception to get rid of this error.
but this exception is in a static state.
I want to make this exception part dynamic.
that is, if this error occurs in other columns, I want to automatically increase the size of the column in those columns.
the following is the plsql code I wrote.

for example, an oracle insert operation may give the same error in the 'explanation' column.
I want to modify the size of the 'explanation' column.
if this error occurs,
I want to perform these operations automatically for each column.

```
DECLARE
SAYAC INTEGER; 
SAYAC_2 INTEGER;
extension_already_exists  EXCEPTION;
PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(extension_already_exists, -12899);
     BEGIN
     SAYAC:=0;
          FOR XX IN (SELECT 
                     FILE_NO,
                            NAME,
                            EV_ADRESI,
                            explanation
                  FROM TABLE_1 
                  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM TABLE_2
                  WHERE TABLE_2.FILE_NO = TABLE_1.FILE_NO )
                  )LOOP
                      BEGIN                  
                  SAYAC:=SAYAC+1;
                          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO
                                    TABLE_2(
                                    FILE_NO,
                                    NAME,
                                    EV_ADRESI,
                                    explanation                                  
                                    ) 
                                    VALUES
                                    (
                                    :A,
                                    :B,
                                    :C,
                                    :D                                    
                                    ) ' 
                          using XX.FILE_NO,XX.NAME,XX.EV_ADRESI,xx.explanation                                                  
                                 ;                
                                  IF MOD(SAYAC,1000)=0 THEN
                                     COMMIT;                                  
                                  END IF;

                         EXCEPTION WHEN extension_already_exists THEN 
                                    dbms_output.put_line('seviye cok buyuk = '||sqlcode||' FILE_NO = '||XX.FILE_NO||','||xx.EV_ADRESI);--this error may occur in other columns
                          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE TABLE_2 MODIFY EV_ADRESI,explanation VARCHAR2(100)';                              --forexample xx.explanation
                                    NULL;                                                                                                        --I want to make this place dynamic
                       end;     
                  END LOOP; 
            COMMIT;
     END;
```

ORA-12899: value too large for column "HOSPITAL"."table_2"."EV_ADRESI" (actual: 34, maximum: 20)
ORA-06512: at line 20

Comment: Is this the business requirement to increasing column size as and when data received in source table, you can create table1 columns same as table 2 column on first place than start moving data.

Comment: the two tables belong to different databases.
so the two tables are different from each other. Imagine this error ('ORA-12899: value too large for column') for different columns in a table with a large number of columns.
I have to fix these columns one by one.
This is a long process.
I wanted to automate this situation.

Answer (score 2):

That won't work anyway. Even if you capture the error and enlarge the column, you'd miss the offending row as you should repeat the previous insert (which failed).

From my point of view, you should first match columns' datatpyes and then move data from *here* to *there* in a simple manner.

By the way, why did you use dynamic SQL for insert? There's nothing *dynamic* there.

Comment: Not only is dynamic SQL unnecessary, PL/SQL and a loop is also unnecessary

Comment: That's what I meant by "in a simple manner", @a_horse. Should have probably said so. Thank you for doing it for me.